# Invoke not working on VS2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013, invoke

So I have this line of code:

```
Invoke(Sub()pt = PictureBox1.PointToScreen(bounds.Location))
```

I was able to use it on VS2013 without error but when I transferred to VS2008 there was an error saying "Expression Expected". Is there a way to use this code in VS2008? because I don't know how to use delegates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Sub` in a lambda expression was not possible until VS2010.  The logical alternative is:

```
    Dim pt As Point = DirectCast(Me.Invoke(Function() PictureBox1.PointToScreen(Bounds.Location)), Point)
```

Which is in fact superior to the original since it doesn't have to capture any variables.